# Как просмотреть отправленный/полученный заголовок при переходе на страницу

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, firefox, браузер, firebug

Все привет!
Подскажите плиз как в google-developer-tools или в firebug просмотреть отправленные заголовки при переходе на другую страницу?
Проблема в том при переходе на новую страницу старый лог запросов(с предыдущей страницы) удалится и заполняется данными с новой страницы. Такая же проблема с профилированием, если включить профилирование на странице и перейти на новую то профилирование отключается. Как это можно изменить?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark. Чтоб наверняка и с гарантией.

Comment: А нельзя просто одним браузером обойтись, без установки доп. софта?

Comment: Тем более он не показывает зашифрованный трафик